# SATA-II SSD Raid 0 slow on Windows-7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, raid, sata

I have 2 SSDs and made a RAID 0 with the on-board controller of my mainboard.

But i only get 130 megabyte/second average read/write speed which seems to be pretty slow for me even for SATA 2 which has up to 300 megabyte/second.

I expected at least 400 megabyte/second!

Are there any tricks to make this raid faster?

Windows-7 64bit Professional

Hardware:

- SSDs: OCZ Agility 2 60gb SATA 2
- Mainboard: nVidia nForce ?????

Comment: Do you have the latest RAID controller drivers?  Does your RAID controller offer a AHCI setting? (make sure it is ON)